# Trying to place a binance futures trailing stop order using python?

Tags: cryptography, binance, binance-api-client

I have got so far,

#changing the margin
client.futures_change_margin_type(symbol = symbol_buy, marginType = 'ISOLATED')

#changing the leverage
client.futures_change_leverage(symbol = symbol_buy, leverage = 1)

shared.client.futures_create_order( symbol=symbol_buy, side = 'SELL', type='TRAILING_STOP_LOSS', quantity = 100)

and i'm thus getting this error below

---

BinanceAPIException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
3
4 #orderdetails_buy = shared.client_future.futures_create_order( symbol=symbol_buy, side = 'BUY', type='MARKET', quantity = 100)
----> 5 orderdetails_sell = shared.client_future.futures_create_order( symbol=symbol_buy, side = 'SELL', type='TRAILING_STOP_LOSS', quantity = 100)
6

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py in futures_create_order(self, **params)
5289
5290         """
-> 5291         return self._request_futures_api('post', 'order', True, data=params)
5292
5293     def futures_place_batch_order(self, **params):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py in _request_futures_api(self, method, path, signed, **kwargs)
331         uri = self._create_futures_api_uri(path)
332
--> 333         return self._request(method, uri, signed, True, **kwargs)
334
335     def _request_futures_data_api(self, method, path, signed=False, **kwargs) -> Dict:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py in _request(self, method, uri, signed, force_params, **kwargs)
307
308         self.response = getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs)
--> 309         return self._handle_response(self.response)
310
311     @staticmethod

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py in _handle_response(response)
316         """
317         if not (200 <= response.status_code < 300):
--> 318             raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
319         try:
320             return response.json()

BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1116): Invalid orderType.

Answer (score 0):

you've probably solved this by now but with binance futures, I don't think there is a TRAILING_STOP_LOSS trade type via API just yet, available order types are (from the docs):

Order types (orderTypes, type):

- LIMIT
- MARKET
- STOP
- STOP_MARKET
- TAKE_PROFIT
- TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET
- TRAILING_STOP_MARKET

[https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#public-endpoints-info][1]